# T4MVC hidden model classes from view dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I've noticed recently that when adding views to controller methods, the dialog doesn't list any of my model classes. I can still generate views and specify the model to be used but it is no longer available in the dialogue options.(currently got v2.10.0)

Cheers
Tim

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're doing. Can you give a more detailed description of the situation? How is this related to T4MVC?

Comment: If I create a new method in my controller, right click and select add view, the dialog (when i select strongly type view) doesn't list my model classes in the Model class dropdown. I assumed this was related to T4MVC as I noticed it shortly after installing it.

Comment: I wouldn't think it would affect it. Can you try a clean project with and without T4MVC to see if that makes a difference? If it does, I'll investigate!

Comment: I have a similar problem as well, I think.  Some of my model classes do not appear in the drop down menu of the Add view dialog :/